# decode data stored in hbase database

Tags: hbase

I have following data stored in hbase & want to decode, is there any way to do it?

Input

```
#Alfresco_Server\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0A\x7F\xFF\xFE\x8C\xB8\x01\xED\x9F column=S:\xF5\xD5\x0C, timestamp=1594640932631, value=\x02\x06\x06\xA0\x92\xBC\x9F\xB4.\x88'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02U\x06\x0C\x06\x8B\xA8\x05\x06\x00\x06\x00


RTU_server_new\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x7F\xFF\xF E\x8D\x89\x01X\x9F column=S:\xE1\x84\x06, timestamp=1591134247837, value=\x02\x06\x06\xF8\xC3\xB9\x9E\xA7.\x88'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02;\x9C\x11\x1F\xD0\x01)\xCE\x03\xF9\x03\x8B\x14\x1E\xBB\x04\xF8\x081\xC5\x0B
```

Was able to decode only timestamp using python

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
print (dt.fromtimestamp(1511356398000 / 1000))
```

Comment: What comprises the row key ? What are their types ?

Comment: Ramachandran.A.G. It's in the form of byte [ ]. Can be taken as a row identifier.